# Primefaces Calendar: does not hide

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

i got this jsf-primefaces webapp and i dont know why my p:calendar components dont hide themselves on date selection, like in the showcase

heres one of my calendars

```
<p:calendar id="dateUntil"
    value="#{absenceController.event.endDate}"
    timeZone="#{absenceController.timeZone}" required="true"
    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy : HH" stepHour="12" label="Bis" locale="de"
    navigator="true" mask="true" readonlyInput="true"
    mindate="#{absenceController.event.startDate}">
    <f:attribute name="dateFrom"
        value="#{absenceController.event.startDate}" />
    <f:validator validatorId="primeDateRangeValidator" />
</p:calendar>
```

and they all act the exact same, it works, but to hide that damn datepicker i have to press esc or to click somewhere outside the component

but i want them to hide on selection... can anybody tell me what im doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: is there any output in the logs?

Comment: nope, there isnt...
everything runs cmoothly ecxept it doesnt hide and i dont want to have an actionlistener just to hide that thing when it should be doing it by default...

Comment: You have set readOnly to true and required true, could that be contradicting itsselfe since it marks the value as radonly, but you require a value to be set.

Comment: just tested that, didnt solve the problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calendar-component does only auto-hide if no time-selection is used (only days).